# Bluebird.js Unhandled Rejection Error using request

Tags: node.js, bluebird, hapi.js

I am trying to make a call to an API to grab some data. When the call returns **valid** data, it works! However, when it hits a API error, or an error I want to create based off the data response, I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Data not found!
at Request.request.post [as _callback]
.
.
```

These are the files I am using:

```
let grabSomeData = new BluebirdPromise((resolve, reject) => {

  pullers.grabData(dataID, (err, res) => {

    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }

    return resolve(res);
  });


});

grabSomeData.then((fulfilled, rejected) => {
  console.log('res: ' + fulfilled);
  console.log('rej: ' + rejected);
});
```

In my other file making the http request,

```
grabData(dataID, grabDataCallback)  {

  let bodyObj = {
    query: dataByIDQuery,
    variables: {
      id: dataID
    }
  };

  // grab the data
  request.post(
    {
      url: dataURL,
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj)
    }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {

        if (err) {
          return grabDataCallback(err);
        }

        let res = JSON.parse(body);

        if (res.data.dataByID !== null) {
          return grabDataCallback(null, res.data.dataByID);
        }

        return grabDataCallback(Boom.notFound('Data not found!'));
      }
  );

}
```

Comment: what does `console.log(res.data.dataByID)` gives you

Comment: When purposefully testing for an error, it will not reach this far. It will display the error above. When testing for valid data, it will print the data just fine @p0k8_

Comment: use the last return statement in the else block `if(res.data.dataByID !== null) { return grabDataCallback(null, res.data.dataByID); } else { return grabDataCallback(Boom.notFound('Data not found!')); }`

Comment: @p0k8_ Just tried this, I am getting the same error. I believe it has to do with the way I am handling the reject/resolve using a callback.

Comment: yes, you haven't declared the `catch` block to handle the reject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
grabSomeData.then((fulfilled, rejected) => {
  console.log('res: ' + fulfilled);
  console.log('rej: ' + rejected);
});
```

You need to use:

```
grabSomeData.then((fulfilled) => {
  console.log('res: ' + fulfilled);
}, (rejected) => {
  console.log('rej: ' + rejected);
});
```

Or:

```
grabSomeData.then((fulfilled) => {
  console.log('res: ' + fulfilled);
}).catch((rejected) => {
  console.log('rej: ' + rejected);
});
```

For more info on the unhandled rejection warnings (that will be fatal errors in the future) see this answer:

- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)

Comment: Ok Awesome!, now would this same principle work with Promise.all (because I am pulling multiple things asynchronously at once?

Comment: @nicolascoding Yes. When you run Promise.all(...) then you either have to give to functions as arguments to then like `Promise.all(...).then((val) => console.log('value:', val), (err) => console.log(err));` or use then with one function and catch with the second one like this `Promise.all(...).then((val) => console.log('value:', val)).catch((err) => console.log(err));` but your `val` will be an array.