# Unhandled rejection Error - horseman

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-horseman

Im trying to run the example code from horsemanjs slightly modified:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();
horseman
    .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0')
    .open('http://www.google.com')
    .type('input[name="q"]', 'github')
    .click('[name="btnK"]')
    .keyboardEvent('keypress', 16777221)
    .waitForSelector('div.g')
    .plainText()
    .log()
    .close();
```

It did work some days ago, but suddenly decided not to. I get this when I run it:

```
➜ Debug=horseman node test.js
   horseman using PhantomJS from phantomjs-prebuilt module +0ms
   horseman .setup() creating phantom instance 1 +3ms
   horseman phantom created +195ms
   horseman .close(). +13ms
Unhandled rejection Error
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous(/home/halvor/BettingSource/node_modules/node-phantom-simple/node-phantom-simple.js:612:14)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

With Bluebird debug:

```
➜  BettingSource DEBUG=horseman BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=1 node test.js                                                                             
    horseman using PhantomJS from phantomjs-prebuilt module +0ms
    horseman .setup() creating phantom instance 1 +3ms
    horseman phantom created +149ms
    horseman .close(). +16ms
Unhandled rejection HeadlessError: Error parsing JSON from phantom: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
Data from phantom was:
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/halvor/BettingSource/node_modules/node-phantom-simple/node-phantom-simple.js:612:14)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
From previous event:
    at prepare (/home/halvor/BettingSource/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/index.js:54:9)
    at new Horseman (/home/halvor/BettingSource/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/index.js:155:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/halvor/BettingSource/test.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:540:3
```

Phantomjs works from the terminal and I've tried to reinstall the node modules. I must note that have very little experience with node.

Note: To install phantomjs/horseman I did the following:

1. Downloaded the tar.gz file from phantomjs website and extracted it, placed it in bath /home/bin
2. Ran npm install phantom in /home/halvor/BettingSource
3. Ran npm install phantomjs
4. Ran npm install node-horseman

Both of the times I installed phantomjs it said phantomjs not found in path and downloaded it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error came from an .htpasswd file in the same directory. Once I deleted it everything worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle promise rejections with:

```
.catch(err => {
    // handle the error here
});
```

for every promise that is created in your program. Otherwise it will cash for any rejection in the promise chain.

See this answer for more details:

- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)