# How to throw exception from async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an async function that I expect to throw exception on failure. However something seems to preventing this:

by omitting the try catch blocks I expect an exception to be thrown which I want to handle outside of the function.

The actual result I get is somewhat confusing:

`(node:10636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): E11000 duplicate key error index.`

`(node:10636) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

```
async f(obj) {
    await db.collection('...').save(obj);
}
```

I get the same result when I try to catch the exception and throw something else instead:

```
async f(obj) {
    try {
        await db.collection('...').save(obj);
    } catch(e) {
        throw e.message;
    }
}
```

The function is called from a try block, so don't see how this is an Unhandled Promise.

I am trying to use `f` as a parameter of another function:

```
g(obj, handler) {
    try {
        handler(obj);
    } catch(e);
        ...
    }
}

g(objToSave, f);
```

Comment: As a side note, your rethrow is incorrect... You should be using `catch(e) { throw e; }`. Because (1) `e.message` is a string and you should not just throw a string and (2) `e` may include other parameters that would be useful at the next level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ultimately, what you're trying to do is calling an asynchronous function `f` in a synchronous function `g`, which won't work (that would be the equivalent of being able to turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous function).

Instead, `g` either has to be `async` as well, or it should properly handle the promise returned by `f`. However, [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926390/how-to-throw-exception-from-async-function/42928209#comment72951567_42926454) you state that the function represented by `f` may not always return a promise, in which case the former option would be the easiest to implement:

```
async g(obj, handler) {
  return await handler(obj);
}
```

This will also work if `handler` doesn't return a promise, but just a value (which is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description)).

Calling `g` (again) requires either an async function, or code to handle its returned promise:

```
g(objToSave, f).then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: The simpler form is `return Promise.resolve(handler(obj))`. `return await` is rarely if ever necessary.

Comment: @lonesomeday true, but `return await` looks better IMO :)

Answer (score 22):

```
async f(obj) {
    try {
        await db.collection('...').save(obj);
    } catch(e) {
        throw e.message;
    }
}
```

> The function is called from a try block, so don't see how this is an Unhandled Promise.

What is unhandled here is the rejection of a promise returned by the `f()` function, not by the `.save()` method. So this will not cause that problem:

```
async f(obj) {
    try {
        await db.collection('...').save(obj);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }
}
```

Throwing an exception in async function **always rejects the promise** that is returned **by that function**.

To catch the exception you either have to do this in another async function:

```
try {
    asyncFunc();
} catch (err) {
    // you have the error here
}
```

or you can add a rejection handler explicitly:

```
asyncFunc().catch(err => {
    // you have the error here
});
```

If you are catching the exception and throwing another exception then you get the same problem, just in a different function.

You either have to add a promise rejection handler and not throw an exception or return a rejected promise there - or run that function in another async function that handles the exception instead of rethrowing the same or new exception.

To sum it up: **Every `async` function returns a promise. Every promise needs to have a rejection handler.**

The rejection handler is added using a two-function `.then()` or with `.catch()`, or with `try { await asyncFunction(); } catch (err) { ... }`

When you have a promise rejection with no rejection handler, you will get a warning in older versions of Node and a fatal error in newer versions of Node - see this answer for more details:

- **[Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)**

Comment: I inferred from _"The function is called from a try block"_ that the OP means the `f` function is being called from a `try/catch` block.

Comment: The call of the `f` function looks like: `try{ f() } catch(e) { console.log(e) }` inside a non-async function. If I rewrite to `f().catch(...)` it works, however I would prefer another option because `f` is a parameter of the calling function and might not return a promise.

Comment: @user1063963 if you're calling it from a non-async function, it's not going to work: asynchonicity is "viral", each calling function has to either be `async` as well (and you'd use `await`), or you need to properly handle the returned promise (if there is one). You should probably update your question to reflect what _exactly_ it is you're doing.

Comment: I think you forgot an `await` in `try {
    asyncFunc();
}`

Answer (score 1):

> which I want to handle outside of the function

That's the only thing you forgot to do. (Which is why the warning is complaining about an *unhandled* rejection). Your function `f` is working fine.

You cannot throw a synchronous exception from an `async function`, everything is asynchronous and exceptions will lead to a rejection of the result promise. That is what you will need to catch:

```
function g(obj, handler) {
    try {
        Promise.resolve(handler(obj)).catch(e => {
            console.error("asynchronous rejection", e);
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.error("synchronous exception", e);
    }
}
// or just
async function g(obj, handler) {
    try {
        await handler(obj);
//      ^^^^^
    } catch(e) {
        console.error("error", e);
    }
}

g(objToSave, f);
```