# List all files in a remote server in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm using this script for listing all files in a server

```
var PromiseFtp = require('promise-ftp');

  var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  ftp.connect({host: ipServer, user: user, password: password})
  .then(function (serverMessage) {
    return ftp.list('/directory/',false);
  }).then(function () {
    return ftp.end();
  });
```

How I can print all files of the directory?

Comment: are you sure you follow the examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
  var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  ftp.connect({host: ipServer, user: user, password: password})
  .then(function (serverMessage) {
    return ftp.list('/directory/',false);
  }).then(function (list) {
    console.log(list);
    return ftp.end();
  });
```

But make sure to also add some rejections handlers and handle errors correctly. See this for more info: [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)