# Axios post stay on pending

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

This is a simple Post request using Axios inside Vue:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    props: {
        msg: String
    },
    mounted () {
        const code = 'test'
        const url = 'http://localhost:3456/'
        axios.post(url, code, { headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', } }).then(this.successHandler).catch(this.errorHandler)
    },
    methods: {
        successHandler (res) {
            console.log(res.data)
        },
        errorHandler (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The Get method works fine. But Post stay as "Pending" on Network tab. I can confirm that there is a Post method on my webservice and it return something (tested on Postman).

**UPDATE**

Sending code as a param:

```
axios(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    params: {
        code : 'test'
    },
}).then(this.successHandler).catch(this.errorHandler)
```

**WEBSERVICE**

```
server.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const { code }  = req.params

    const options = {
        validate: 'soft',
        cheerio: {},
        juice: {},
        beautify: {},
        elements: []
    }

    heml(code, options).then(
        ({ html, metadata, errors }) => {
            res.send({metadata, html, errors})
            next()      
        })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's issue with your axios request structure. 
Try this:

```
const URL = *YOUR_URL*;
axios(URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: *YOUR_PAYLOAD*,
  })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
```

If you're sending a query param:

```
axios(URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    params: {
     code: 'your_string'
    },
  })
```

if it is path variable you can set your url:

```
const url = `http://localhost:3456/${code}`
```

Let me know if the issue still persists

Comment: Now something happens. But it's an error: code: "InvalidContent", message: "Invalid JSON: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1". My webservice expect a parameters called code and it's must be a string.

Comment: I would recommend to stick with  application/json content type. You should send {code: 'your_string'} and on server side you would get a JSON and you can retrieve 'code' key from request payload. The issue with your post request is fixed it's an issue with parsing.

Comment: OK, I wil try this. Just another question: I'm running webservice on localhost:3456 and vue app on localhost:8080. This is a problem?

Comment: No that's not the problem you're in the same domain network. Unless you deploy it somewhere then you need to enable CORS for development purpose. I hope this would clarify most of the things, Let me know if you have any other query. happy to help

Comment: make sure that you use both 'then' and 'catch' Otherwise you will not handle errors and you will get that warning. check out this you would get the basic understanding
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505

Comment: Found the problem. My webservice expect code as a param.

Comment: But I test with your code and it not working. The parameter is not arriving in webservice. Could you see the code above?

Comment: which one is required  Path varaible or Query Pram? Please specify

Comment: I posted the Post route of webservice above.

Comment: are you using expressJs for server implementation ?

Comment: No, I'm using Restify

Comment: I'm using bodyParser

Comment: bodyparser is for request body parsing. Try query parser as well.

Comment: Fixed! Instead using `const { code }= req.params` on webservice, I changed to `const { code } = req.body`

Answer (score 1):

I also was facing the same. Network call was pending all the time and Mitigated it by passing the response back from server.js(route file) e.g(res.json(1);) and it resolved the issue